# Conditional Location routing - nginx

Tags: nginx, webserver

Issue:

I have two applications served by one **nginx 1.5.5** webserver on one domain, **www.domain.com**.

Because they both listen on the same locations I added a header of APP = ONE or TWO which I set when the application is first called. Example below.

```
location ^/APPONE  {
            proxy_pass http://APPONE;
                add_header              APP             ONE;
                proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
                proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }

location ^/APPTWO  {
            proxy_pass http://APPTWO;
                add_header              APP             TWO;
                proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
                proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }
```

Due to poor application design, the applications both request the below locations not using the application name as a docroot. Like the example below.

```
location ~ ^/(framerwork1/|framerwork2/|framerwork3/) {
            proxy_pass http://APPONE;
                add_header              APP             ONE;
                proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
                proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }

location ~ ^/(framerwork1/|framerwork2/|framerwork3/) {
                proxy_pass http://APPTWO;
                add_header              APP             TWO;
                proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
                proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

  }
```

So, I added the APP ONE or TWO header to separate the two, but my if statements to proxy them based on the header is not being accepted by Nginx. Example Below.

```
if ($http_host ~ 'APP=ONE') {

       location ~ ^/(framerwork1/|framerwork2/|framerwork3/) {
                proxy_pass http://APPONE;
                add_header              APP             ONE;
                proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
                proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }

if ($http_host ~ 'APP=TWO') {

       location ~ ^/(framerwork1/|framerwork2/|framerwork3/) {
                proxy_pass http://APPTWO;
                add_header              APP             TWO;
                proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
                proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }
```

Question: How can I proxy these two application successfully based on the header? Please note, I am unable to use a different server block or domain. They must be the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to be clear, what are you hoping will happen when you set "add_header APP ONE;" ?

Comment: @Danack That it will add a header variable that I can use for filtering. Is this the wrong way to do this?

Comment: The header will be added to the request to the proxy_server on the request made to /APPONE, it won't be set by clients on future requests they make to the location /framerwork1 .

Comment: @Danack Why is that? Surely any request that is proxied through will have the header added? Is this not correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so a request is coming in to www.domain.com/APPONE . You don't say exactly what is being requested through the URL www.domain.com/framerwork1/ but lets imagine it's an image that is required by the page served at /APPONE as that is simple to understand.

When you are setting the header through 'add_header' it is being set in the second array in "Client" -> Nginx -> PHP Proxy.

When the client then makes the request to the image at www.domain.com/framerwork1/ it has no idea that you are hoping to have a header set to be able to determine if the image was requested by APPONE, or something else.

Even if you set the header on the response for www.domain.com/APPONE clients do not blindly echo headers sent to them back to server for subsequent requests.

Or to put it bluntly, I think you've misunderstood where the headers are being passed, and that there isn't really a way to determine what application is making a request to the /framerwork1/ URL like that. You have to do this either via separate domain names (or sub-domain) or by doing it inside your application with things like looking at which application the user is logged into.